# Changing my paypal from 1 time payment to paypal sub

Tags: php, paypal

So i have a membership site were users need to pay x amount each month to use it at the moment i have coded it so that they need to checkout each month them self of course users are asking me to change this so it takes the payments on auto. The user needs to go to my membership page pick one which then takes 1 payment . I have gone to paypal and made a sub button but wanted some help to add it into my current payment coding

```
      <a class="cd-select" href="upgradeaccount.php?Popular=2">Select</a>
                                <?php




            if (isset($_GET['Popular'])) {



// Setup class
require_once('paypal.class.php');  // include the class file
$p = new paypal_class;             // initiate an instance of the class
$p->paypal_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';   // testing paypal url
//$p->paypal_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';     // paypal url

// setup a variable for this script (ie: 'http://www.domain.com/paypal.php')
$this_script = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

// if there is not action variable, set the default action of 'process'
if (empty($_GET['action'])) $_GET['action'] = 'process';  

switch ($_GET['action']) {

   case 'process':      // Process and order...

      // There should be no output at this point.  To process the POST data,
      // the submit_paypal_post() function will output all the HTML tags which
      // contains a FORM which is submited instantaneously using the BODY onload
      // attribute.  In other words, don't echo or printf anything when you're
      // going to be calling the submit_paypal_post() function.

      // This is where you would have your form validation  and all that jazz.
      // You would take your POST vars and load them into the class like below,
      // only using the POST values instead of constant string expressions.

      // For example, after ensureing all the POST variables from your custom
      // order form are valid, you might have:
      //
      // $p->add_field('first_name', $_POST['first_name']);
      // $p->add_field('last_name', $_POST['last_name']);


      $p->add_field('business', 'admin@mydomain.com');
      $p->add_field('return', $this_script.'?action=success');
      $p->add_field('cancel_return', $this_script.'?action=cancel');
      $p->add_field('notify_url', $this_script.'?action=ipn');
      $p->add_field('item_name', 'mydomain.com Popular Account Upgrade');
      $p->add_field('amount', '2.00');

      $p->submit_paypal_post(); // submit the fields to paypal
      //$p->dump_fields();      // for debugging, output a table of all the fields
      break;

   case 'success':      // Order was successful...

      // This is where you would probably want to thank the user for their order
      // or what have you.  The order information at this point is in POST 
      // variables.  However, you don't want to "process" the order until you
      // get validation from the IPN.  That's where you would have the code to
      // email an admin, update the database with payment status, activate a
      // membership, etc.  

      echo "<html><head><title>Success</title></head><body><h3>Thank you for your order.</h3>";
      foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { echo "$key: $value<br>"; }
      echo "</body></html>";

      // You could also simply re-direct them to another page, or your own 
      // order status page which presents the user with the status of their
      // order based on a database (which can be modified with the IPN code 
      // below).

      break;

   case 'cancel':       // Order was canceled...

      // The order was canceled before being completed.
 echo "sorry ";
      echo "<html><head><title>Canceled</title></head><body><h3>The order was canceled.</h3>";
      echo "</body></html>";

      break;

   case 'ipn':          // Paypal is calling page for IPN validation...

      // It's important to remember that paypal calling this script.  There
      // is no output here.  This is where you validate the IPN data and if it's
      // valid, update your database to signify that the user has payed.  If
      // you try and use an echo or printf function here it's not going to do you
      // a bit of good.  This is on the "backend".  That is why, by default, the
      // class logs all IPN data to a text file.

      if ($p->validate_ipn()) {

         // Payment has been recieved and IPN is verified.  This is where you
         // update your database to activate or process the order, or setup
         // the database with the user's order details, email an administrator,
         // etc.  You can access a slew of information via the ipn_data() array.

         // Check the paypal documentation for specifics on what information
         // is available in the IPN POST variables.  Basically, all the POST vars
         // which paypal sends, which we send back for validation, are now stored
         // in the ipn_data() array.

         // For this example, we'll just email ourselves ALL the data.
         echo"  worked";
         $subject = 'Instant Payment Notification - Recieved Payment';
         $to = 'myemail@live.co.uk';    //  your email
         $body =  "An instant payment notification was successfully recieved\n";
         $body .= "from ".$p->ipn_data['payer_email']." on ".date('m/d/Y');
         $body .= " at ".date('g:i A')."\n\nDetails:\n";

         foreach ($p->ipn_data as $key => $value) { $body .= "\n$key: $value"; }
         mail($to, $subject, $body);
      }
      break;
 }     

            }
```

paypalclass

```
class paypal_class {

   var $last_error;                 // holds the last error encountered

   var $ipn_log;                    // bool: log IPN results to text file?

   var $ipn_log_file;               // filename of the IPN log
   var $ipn_response;               // holds the IPN response from paypal   
   var $ipn_data = array();         // array contains the POST values for IPN

   var $fields = array();           // array holds the fields to submit to paypal


   function paypal_class() {

      // initialization constructor.  Called when class is created.

      $this->paypal_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

      $this->last_error = '';

      $this->ipn_log_file = '.ipn_results.log';
      $this->ipn_log = true; 
      $this->ipn_response = '';

      // populate $fields array with a few default values.  See the paypal
      // documentation for a list of fields and their data types. These defaul
      // values can be overwritten by the calling script.

      $this->add_field('rm','2');           // Return method = POST
      $this->add_field('cmd','_xclick'); 

   }

   function add_field($field, $value) {

      // adds a key=>value pair to the fields array, which is what will be 
      // sent to paypal as POST variables.  If the value is already in the 
      // array, it will be overwritten.

      $this->fields["$field"] = $value;
   }

   function submit_paypal_post() {

      // this function actually generates an entire HTML page consisting of
      // a form with hidden elements which is submitted to paypal via the 
      // BODY element's onLoad attribute.  We do this so that you can validate
      // any POST vars from you custom form before submitting to paypal.  So 
      // basically, you'll have your own form which is submitted to your script
      // to validate the data, which in turn calls this function to create
      // another hidden form and submit to paypal.

      // The user will briefly see a message on the screen that reads:
      // "Please wait, your order is being processed..." and then immediately
      // is redirected to paypal.

      echo "<html>\n";
      echo "<head><title>Processing Payment...</title></head>\n";
      echo "<body onLoad=\"document.forms['paypal_form'].submit();\">\n";
      echo "<center><h2>Please wait, your order is being processed and you";
      echo " will be redirected to the paypal website.</h2></center>\n";
      echo "<form method=\"post\" name=\"paypal_form\" ";
      echo "action=\"".$this->paypal_url."\">\n";

      foreach ($this->fields as $name => $value) {
         echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$name\" value=\"$value\"/>\n";
      }
      echo "<center><br/><br/>If you are not automatically redirected to ";
      echo "paypal within 5 seconds...<br/><br/>\n";
      echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Click Here\"></center>\n";

      echo "</form>\n";
      echo "</body></html>\n";

   }

   function validate_ipn() {

      // parse the paypal URL
      $url_parsed=parse_url($this->paypal_url);        

      // generate the post string from the _POST vars aswell as load the
      // _POST vars into an arry so we can play with them from the calling
      // script.
      $post_string = '';    
      foreach ($_POST as $field=>$value) { 
         $this->ipn_data["$field"] = $value;
         $post_string .= $field.'='.urlencode(stripslashes($value)).'&'; 
      }
      $post_string.="cmd=_notify-validate"; // append ipn command

      // open the connection to paypal
      $fp = fsockopen($url_parsed[host],"80",$err_num,$err_str,30); 
      if(!$fp) {

         // could not open the connection.  If loggin is on, the error message
         // will be in the log.
         $this->last_error = "fsockopen error no. $errnum: $errstr";
         $this->log_ipn_results(false);       
         return false;

      } else { 

         // Post the data back to paypal
         fputs($fp, "POST $url_parsed[path] HTTP/1.1\r\n"); 
         fputs($fp, "Host: $url_parsed[host]\r\n"); 
         fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"); 
         fputs($fp, "Content-length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n"); 
         fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"); 
         fputs($fp, $post_string . "\r\n\r\n"); 

         // loop through the response from the server and append to variable
         while(!feof($fp)) { 
            $this->ipn_response .= fgets($fp, 1024); 
         } 

         fclose($fp); // close connection

      }

      if (eregi("VERIFIED",$this->ipn_response)) {

         // Valid IPN transaction.
         $this->log_ipn_results(true);
         return true;       

      } else {

         // Invalid IPN transaction.  Check the log for details.
         $this->last_error = 'IPN Validation Failed.';
         $this->log_ipn_results(false);   
         return false;

      }

   }

   function log_ipn_results($success) {

      if (!$this->ipn_log) return;  // is logging turned off?

      // Timestamp
      $text = '['.date('m/d/Y g:i A').'] - '; 

      // Success or failure being logged?
      if ($success) $text .= "SUCCESS!\n";
      else $text .= 'FAIL: '.$this->last_error."\n";

      // Log the POST variables
      $text .= "IPN POST Vars from Paypal:\n";
      foreach ($this->ipn_data as $key=>$value) {
         $text .= "$key=$value, ";
      }

      // Log the response from the paypal server
      $text .= "\nIPN Response from Paypal Server:\n ".$this->ipn_response;

      // Write to log
      $fp=fopen($this->ipn_log_file,'a');
      fwrite($fp, $text . "\n\n"); 

      fclose($fp);  // close file
   }

   function dump_fields() {

      // Used for debugging, this function will output all the field/value pairs
      // that are currently defined in the instance of the class using the
      // add_field() function.

      echo "<h3>paypal_class->dump_fields() Output:</h3>";
      echo "<table width=\"95%\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"0\">
            <tr>
               <td bgcolor=\"black\"><b><font color=\"white\">Field Name</font></b></td>
               <td bgcolor=\"black\"><b><font color=\"white\">Value</font></b></td>
            </tr>"; 

      ksort($this->fields);
      foreach ($this->fields as $key => $value) {
         echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>".urldecode($value)."&nbsp;</td></tr>";
      }

      echo "</table><br>"; 
   }
}
```

so i just noticed in the paypal class all i need to do is change it to

```
  $this->add_field('rm','2');           // Return method = POST
  $this->add_field('cmd','_xclick-subscriptions');
```

but now getting the error
Invalid Regular period. You must specify valid values for the A3, P3 and T3 parameters for a subscription.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by editing the paypal class and adding this

```
  $this->add_field('rm','2');           // Return method = POST
  $this->add_field('cmd','_xclick-subscriptions'); 
   $this->add_field('a3','2'); 
       $this->add_field('p3','1'); 
          $this->add_field('t3','M'); 
                $this->add_field('src','1');
```